# My measure returns 0 for dates in Date Calendar that are not listed under my table

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I update/tweak the below measure to include all A to D items in table All_OOS_AD[Category], and not just the 'A's?

```
Total OOS A (NS) = SUMX(
    VALUES(All_OOS_AD[Date]), 
    VAR currentDate = [Date]
    RETURN IF(
        CONTAINS(All_OOS_AD, All_OOS_AD[Date], currentDate, All_OOS_AD[Item Category], "A"),
        CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(All_OOS_AD), All_OOS_AD[Item Category] = "A", All_OOS_AD[Date] = currentDate),
        0
    )
)
```

This measure currently only works for 'A' Items; I would like to be able to use the same measure for all A to D items in my table :

| Date | Item Category |
| --- | --- |
| 15.2.23 | A |
| 15.2.23 | A |
| 15.2.23 | A |
| 15.2.23 | B |
| 15.2.23 | D |
| 15.2.23 | D |
| 16.2.23 | B |
| 16.2.23 | D |
| 16.2.23 | D |
| 16.2.23 | D |
| 16.2.23 | C |
| 17.2.23 | A |
| 17.2.23 | D |
| 17.2.23 | D |
| 17.2.23 | D |
| 17.2.23 | D |
| 20.2.23 | C |
| 20.2.23 | C |
| 20.2.23 | C |

I want the measure to count all A,B,C & D items for a specific date and return 0 if there is no A,B,C or D item for that specific date in the above table:

| Date | Item Category | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15.2.23 | A | 3 |
| 15.2.23 | B | 1 |
| 15.2.23 | C | 0 |
| 15.2.23 | D | 2 |
| 16.2.23 | A | 0 |
| 16.2.23 | B | 1 |
| 16.2.23 | C | 1 |
| 16.2.23 | D | 3 |
| 17.2.23 | A | 1 |
| 17.2.23 | B | 0 |
| 17.2.23 | C | 0 |
| 17.2.23 | D | 4 |
| 20.2.23 | A | 0 |
| 20.2.23 | B | 0 |
| 20.2.23 | C | 3 |
| 20.2.23 | D | 0 |

The measure I currently use, for A to D items, reruns a 0 for dates that are not listed within my table (All_OOS_AD) - it picks this up from the main DATE Table which includes all dates (earliest date to Today), and I don't want this. I want the measure only to return a 0 for dates included in All_OOS_AD table:

```
Total OOS A-D/Date (NS) T1 *NB* = 
 VAR Total_OOS_AD =
       COUNTROWS(
           SUMMARIZE(
               All_OOS_AD,All_OOS_AD[Name],All_OOS_AD[Date]
               )
               )
 VAR Result =
 IF(
     Total_OOS_AD =BLANK(), 
     0, 
     Total_OOS_AD
     )
RETURN
Result
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The date table in your case should be based on the distinct values of the column date in your All_OOS_AD :

```
DateTable = DISTINCT(All_OOS_AD[Date])
```

[image]

Then you need to create a calculated table that includes every combination of date and item category.

```
AllCombinations = CROSSJOIN('Date', 'ItemCategory')
```

[image]

Then you count the number of occurrences for each combination of date and item category, and return 0 instead of BLANK for combinations with no occurrences :

```
ItemCountMeasure = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('All_OOS_AD'),
    FILTER(
        ALL(All_OOS_AD),
        All_OOS_AD[Date] IN VALUES('DateTable'[Date])
        && All_OOS_AD[Item Category] IN VALUES ('ItemCategoryTable'[Item Category])
    )
) + 0
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Amira, this measure doesn't return any values. It accepts the measure but when I use the measure in a table visual I get 'Can't display the visual'

DateTable = DISTINCT(All_OOS_AD[Date])

Comment: See Details: 
MdxScript(Model) (248, 37) Calculation error in measure 'FORMULAS'[DateTable]: A table of
multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: @Cristina did you follow the solution step by step ?

Comment: I have created a new measure for DateTable = DISTINCT(All_OOS_AD[Date]) as you indicated and then I've tested this in a table and realised it's not returning any values (like in your example) - so I've stopped here. Should I go ahead and use this measure even though this won't return any dates?

Comment: Ok - I see where I went wrong the first time. I was creating a measure instead of a calculated table. Now I've created 2 calculated tables, one for Unique Date in All_OOS_AD and one for AllCombinations - but in this last table I get an additional column 'DATE' which I can't delete/remove (I've attached an additional photo).

Comment: I think I've almost got there but for some reason the measure 'ItemCountMeasure' returns extra empty rows in my visual and also, it wont allow me to filter the visual by date  (both the UniqueDate & Item CAT A to D filter but when I add the measure it won't  filter any more)

Comment: Check my profile info and you can contact me on Linkedin so we can work on this :)